# Get values from dynamically generated fields

Tags: jquery

I have this table where I can dynamically add rows. I'm able to detect the change on the first row, however when I generate few more I'm unable to track the change in the fields. Any suggestion?

```js
var i = 0;

$("#add").click(function() {
  ++i;
  $("#dynamicTable").append(`
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="addmore['+${i}+'][ic_number]" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="addmore['+${i}+'][age]" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    `);
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});

$('#dynamicTable').each(function() {
  $('input[name="addmore[' + i + '][age]"').on('change', function() {
    console.log('hi')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamicTable">
  <thead class="bg-primary tx-white">
    <th scope="col">Identity Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Age</th>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][id_number]" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][age]" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, as inputs are dynamically generated you need to bind it with static elements . i.e : `$(document).on("change","yourinputfieldclass",function(){ //you codes })` .Also you can give `class name` for age input so it would be easy to handle .

Comment: Thanks Swati. Got it.